# Slow usb charger for my smart phone?

Tags: batteries, usb, charger, telephone, smart

I read that the optimal charger for smartphone batteries is 3.92v (to reduce degradation). Is it possible to implement a system that allows an external "charger" to cause charging to stop at this point?

Added:  People have pointed out that the external USB power supply is not actually a charger and that the charging is carried out by circuitry inside the phone.

Would it be possible to design and implement a circuit external to the the phone that terminated charging when the battery had reached some 'less than 100% charged' state, that allowed a longer battery cycle lifetime and greater whole of life capacity?.

Comment: why do you believe that the phone would even charge if you supplied below spec voltage?

Comment: Ask the person who wrote the article that you don't want to show us.

Comment: https://android.gadgethacks.com/how-to/set-charging-limit-your-android-device-avoid-excess-battery-wear-0176280/

Comment: This is a moot question. Charging circuitry on modern phones and quality of Li-Ion batteries are good enough to last several years. Battery in my ASUS Zen-phone is still working just fine for more than 6 years. By that time the phone generation will change at least three times, so most people will change the phone instead of worrying about "battery degradation".

Comment: @Ale..chenski Whether your claim re lifetimes is correct is moot :-). Note that Apple have relatively recently been "outed" for reducing product clock rate / power use progressively to maintain apparent battery run times. Whether others do this and how aggressively is unknown (to me at least). I agress that SOME LiIon batteries seem to have calendar lives well in excess of the claimed or observed norm. I have on a few occasions replaced batteries in "brand name" products that have massively lost capacity.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon, "reducing product clock rate" (and gating/reducing local voltage supplies) is in fact the baseline technology to reduce power consumption of electronic devices. Most parts of modern microprocessors just stop the clock completely, while a small core controller maintains minimal clock rate to be just enough to respond in human real time (which is slow). And if the power resource is low, they do it more aggressively while the device maintains its basic functionality. Whoever "outed" Apple is just grossly ignorant in modern technology.

Comment: @Ale..chenski  I'm *very* well aware of how power consumption is controlled. | I usually maintain a clove of garlic, several super extended bargepoles and a firewall between myself and anything-Apple, so I don't know the fine detail of what happened **BUT** my strong recollection is that they admitted to doing essentially what was claimed, which was progressively reducing system throughput to maintain operating time as the battery capacity faded. As a user selectable option it would be commendable. As an "always LOOK good" ploy, less so.

Comment: @Jonathan - I've edited my answer and focused on a single method. This comes close to what you wanted. It could be implemented with an Arduino, a current sense resistor, a transistor (probably FET) to terminate charging and a micro-USB plug to socket lead.

Comment: @Jonathan - As the question was put on hold as off topic [tm] I've taken the liberty of rewriting it as a design question and provided a design answer that comes close to matching your need. I'll ask the admins to reopen the question. They MAY do so.

Answer (score 3):

> Is it possible to purchase a usb wall charger that charges at that voltage? Or perhaps 3.9v? I'm not finding anything on google.

The USB charger, as you call it, is *not* charging the battery. It's supplying 5V to the phone. The phone contains a battery charger, which controls charging of the battery. The  charger, inside the phone, regulates the voltage according to the state of charge and desired charging current.

The USB spec says [5V, +0.25V, -0.55V](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB). Your 3.9V would be *wildly* outside the spec. A good phone would decide that the power source is not reliable, and do nothing with it. A bad phone may be damaged by it.

Answer (score 0):

AN EFFECTIVE PRACTICAL LITHIUM ION BATTERY LIFE EXTENSION METHOD.

This method will work with many Lithium Ion battery powered devices that use "USB" (or other) external chargers.

It may not work with some devices that try to operate a 'closed' system that attempts to ensure that only "genuine" chargers are used - but it will work with many of those as well.

It involves inserting a small device in the external charge lead which allows charging current to be monitored and thus for charging to be terminated when the classic CCCV charging cycle switches from CC to CV mode. This is at a point somewhat above the 3.9X v/cell that the question identified but is still at a point which will give useful battery cycle life and whole of life capacity improvement. This is at the expense of a decrease in per cycle charge capacity of typically around 10-15% compared to the absolute maximum achievable.

Devices which use secret mason's handshakes, unusual resistor combinations, digital signalling and other arcane techniques will still usually be amenable to this method as can be completely transparent* up until the moment that it terminates charging.

- *I mention below use of a small resistor as a current sensor. A drop of say 0.1V maximum is unlikely to cause a problem or be detectable in most cases. If desired a Hall cell current sensor will allow completely transparent current sensing.

  ---

A method that will extend battery cycle life and whole of life mAh capacity is to terminate charging when Vbat reaches Vmax. Chargers almost invariable implement "CCCV" charging (constant current followed by constant voltage once Vmax is reached.)

By monitoring charge current and terminating charging when the current starts to drop at the end of the CC phase you get something in the 80%-90% capacity range and useful extended lifetime.

At the start of charge Ichg may ramp up initially so you need a startup timer to preventing charge termination initially. For extra fun, some phones may occasionally drop into a brief low current mode while they do something the maker thinks helps. So a timer to cover this may also be needed.
An eg Arduino would provide the functionality needed with ease.

- Monitor charger current with a small series resistor.
- Determine what typical Ichg is.
- Allow a startup period.
- If needed, allow a delay when Ichg falls too low.
- When Ichg falls to low for more than a predetermined period, terminate charge.

Some phones might need more complex decisions, but these can be seen by observation and, in most cases, the above should suffice.

Comment: This would likely defeat the state-of-charge tracking in the phone.

Comment: @user2943160 You may wish to be more specific than "This" in comments, as I suggested several things. | But, no, wrt the main one I suggested - terminating charging when Ichg indicates that the CC to CV transition had occurred. A state of charge tracker MUST be able to dal with someone terminating charge at any point, and this is an entirely normal charge termination from the phone's point of view. If one must one could occasionally fully charge the battery to reset the SOC system.

Comment: Any external charging.

Comment: @user2943160 I decided that my key offering here was the cessation of charging when the transition between CC and CV charging is detected. I've removed the small comment re external charging which, as you rightly noted, may cause state of charge tracking algorithm errors. | The now sole method covered avoids this problem.

Comment: Wouldn't this require that the phone be turned off during charging, so that the only current drawn is current used to charge the battery?

Comment: @ElliotAlderson I think that comes under " ... Some phones might need more complex decisions, ...". :-) -> If you wanted a simple version, then, yes. || (1.) Monitoring phone charge current and noting the mean and trend would be 'easy enough' if you were using an eg Arduino or similar. I have occasionally charged phones using an inline USB current meter and if not in use by a person they largely settle into a constant current mode. (2) CC charging at C/1 takes about 45-50 minutes from fully flat. Less if part charged. Worst case you need it to have a consistent trend during that period.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson Ideal would be an 'app' that measures battery voltage and terminated charging (which was what the OP originally asked). This may be resisted by the phone designer. Next best is an app that *reports* battery voltage (Bluetooth or earpiece or ...) for an external terminator to act on. A quick web search shows a host of battery voltage monitors and notifiers. Charging terminators may exist but I didn't see any with a quick search. [As you know - Charge termination with charging source connected requires a 'higher level' of hardware control than the maker may be happy with.]